# Regular expression - starting and ending with a specific string

Tags: regex

We have loads of configuration files and I am trying to look for a specific starting the ending of a line using RegEx

```
set ftp {any text here} disabled=yes
```

sample:

```
set ftp disabled=yes

set ftp address=10.0.0.0/24,10.1.1.0/24 disabled=yes

set ftp address=10.0.0.1,10.1.1.1,10.1.2.2 disabled=yes

set ftp address=10.95.140.0/24,10.94.140.0/24 disabled=yes
```

Comment: Which programming language ?

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need**. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/set ftp.*disabled=yes/
```

You may find it helpful to use a site to test your regular expressions.

Comment: Many thanks, i spent almost 5-6 hours trying to figure this out - just shows how simple it is for someone who knows what they are doing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/set ftp \S+ disabled=yes/
```

[demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/7mEvp0/1)